# Cannot select item from GridViewDataComboBoxColumn - DevExpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

[image: Screenshot]

I added a `ComboBox` to the column of my `GridViewEditingMode.Batch` and at the time of displaying the list it does not allow me to select items

```
  List<Productos> lstProd = new List<Productos>();          

     column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
                {
                    p.ValueType = typeof(string);
                    p.TextField = "vcDescEquipo";
                    p.ValueField = "vcIdClaveProv";
                   // p.DataSource = lstProd.ToList();
                    p.BindList(lstProd);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values of this column's editors are not bound to any grid data source's field, I suggest you configure this column as an unbound column. 
Set the column's FieldName property to a custom name that is not used as a filed name in your data source and specify the column's UnboundType property.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T540624/gridview-can-t-select-item-from-gridviewdatacomboboxcolumn-in-batch-mode